# Limiting amount of async BigQuery Jobs running on express server

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I have an express server that is pulling data from Google BigQuery. An `array` of objects is provided. I want to pull sales data for each `store` in a `district`, but the table holds sales information based only on `store` and doesn't have `district` information. I was accomplishing this by sending one query per `district`, but once the array has more than 50 district I get errors. The results are stored in individual CSV files by district. So it is convenient to send individual queries and dump it into the CSVs. BigQuery only allows 50 jobs at a given time. I am looking for the best way to adapt the below code to call `asyncQuery(query)` 50 times then only make the next call when a previous call has returned. I have been trying to work the job status using the `job.getMetadata()` but no luck yet.

Thanks for any help you can offer

```
const array = [{
        district: "north"
        store: "1001,1002"
    },
    {
        district: "south"
        store: "1003"
    },{
        district: "west"
        store: "1004"
    }
]

function apiCall(array) {
    array.forEach(element => {
        let stores = element.store.toString()
        let query = `SELECT store, sku, tot_sales, price
                      FROM big-query-table 
                      WHERE
                      store IN (${stores})`
        asyncQuery(query)
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error('ERROR:', err);
            })
    })
    return "Running Jobs"
}

function asyncQuery(sqlQuery) {

    const options = {
        query: sqlQuery,
        useLegacySql: false,
    };

    let job;

    return bigquery
        .createQueryJob(options)
        .then(results => {
            job = results[0];
            console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);
            return job.promise();
        })
        .then(() => {
            // Get the job's status
            return job.getMetadata();
        })
        .then(metadata => {
            // Check the job's status for errors
            const errors = metadata[0].status.errors;
            if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
                throw errors;
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
            return job.getQueryResults();
        })
        .then(results => {
            const rows = results[0];
            return rows;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
}
```

Comment: What kind of query are you running? Can you post it's code? Can you use one query instead of 20?

Comment: It is a MySQL query, each is the same except store Number is replaced `SELECT * FROM big-query-table WHERE storeNumber = ${StoreNumber}`

Comment: Looking at the full query you posted - there's no aggregation nor sorting of data. You just want to export the full table?

Comment: This is a simplified version of a similar query. My full query joins multiple tables and aggregates. I didn't wont post the entire very large query. This query will return a table similar in structure to my full table. Each job pulls the sales data for only a subset of the stores. My app takes the data that was returned per job and transforms and writes it in a CSV

Answer (score 0):

With BigQuery - and any other columnar analytical database - you really want to avoid doing 50 queries like:

`[*50] SELECT * FROM big-query-table 
       WHERE storeNumber = ${StoreNumber}`

Instead, the best you could do is one query, specifying the columns you are looking for, and all the ids you're looking for:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM big-query-table 
WHERE storeNumber IN ('id1', 'id2', ..., 'id50')
```

Or a straight join:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM big-query-table 
WHERE storeNumber IN (SELECT store_id FROM `table`)
```

Then you won't need to send 50 concurrent queries, and you'll get result in less time and lower cost.

Comment: While your answer makes since to me it will return with over a TB of data with several hundred thousands rows. I am worried about node being able to handle parsing such large amount of data. Is this not a legitimate worry?

Comment: How could it return a TB of data if you only ask for 2 ids?

Comment: Thanks for your interest and help in this question. In an effort to simplify the problem I didn't initially provide adequate information. I updated the question to better explain the problem.